# Wetting liquids should NOT rise in a capillary tube according the gauge (Laplace) pressure formula. But they do!

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics, surface-tension, capillary-action

In this [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_action#/media/File:Capillarity.svg), the capillaries on the left-hand side contain a wetting liquid. Applying the gauge formula for the curved liquid surface we have $P_a-P_l=\frac{2\sigma}{R}^{*}.$ Where $\sigma$ is the surface tension of the liquid and $R$ is the radius of the small curvature. Now the LHS is positive and so is RHS hence $P_a$ is greater than $P_l.$ What does that mean? It means that the atmospheric pressure is more than that of the liquid at the curved surface. Hence the water must fall. But this doesn't happen. On the contrary, the water rises! Where is the mistake?

$*:$ See the derivation section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jurin%27s_law).

Comment: The atmospheric pressure, the liquid pressure (below the surface), and the surface tension force are at equilibrium at the surface.  So there is no driving force for the surface to move down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The water doesn't fall down because the surface tension holds it up.

The surface tension acts tangentially along the line where the blue water meets the tube on the left hand diagram and causes an upward force on the water.

Comment: Thank you. This escaped my thaught.